# get a value inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing Node Js application using  get-proxylist library so my question is how to get the value which is inside the function here is my code:

```
var proxylist = require('get-proxylist');
var array =[]
 proxylist(function(error, result){

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            array.push(result[i]);
        }
    })
console.log(array[0]) // display undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing here with asynchronous operations. At the time`console.log(array[0])` is executed, the callback passed to `proxylist` is not yet executed and `array` is still empty.

Comment: Hey this is not connected to the question directly but can you recommend any good reads on asynchronous operations?

Comment: so what is the solution how can I correct that?